# Request.txt files generated in Gatling

Tags: gatling

After recording a Gatling simulation, I am getting many request.txt files in GATLING\user-files\bodies folder for each submit request on the UI.

These files contain the request data. How can I avoid to get these text files and get the entire code in simulation only.

Comment: i am looking for the same solution did you found something

Answer (score 1):

What about editing the simulations by yourself. You can record the requests and then edit them using any scala-code-editor like IntelliJ, there you can remove all the extra code/files that you don't like